# Is it possible to to use the outer macro parameter is used by inner macro?

Tags: assembly, macros, x86-16, masm, emu8086

```
data segment
    str db "hello$" 
    str2 db "world$" 
data ends  
 
adds macro a,b
    lea si,a
    lea di,b
endm
    
subs macro x,y
    adds x,y
endm  

code segment
assume cs:code,ds:data
start:  mov ax,data
        mov ds,ax
        
        subs str,str2
        
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
        
        end start
        code ends
```

The above is just an example, in case of integers works fine but in this case of strings why it doesn't replace x,y with str,str2???
plz help out me fast I need to work on it for the project.
The error generated by it is:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lack of nested macros is a limitation with EMU8086 and I don't think it is possible. If you used MASM/TASM/JWASM it should handle it properly.

On newer versions of MASM `str` is an instruction on the 386 and it is a good idea to rename `str` to something else to avoid MASM giving an error.

The last 2 lines of your code are reversed and should be:

```
code ends
end start
```

You have to end the current segment with `ends` before ending the program with `end`.

Comment: is there any alternative to achieve it?? in emu8086

Comment: @ViswaDecoders The only way in EMU8086 is to rewrite the way you do the code to avoid one macro calling another. That is the only thing I can say. Rather than using macros you could simply create functions.

Comment: @Micheal Petch ok that's fine